# R how to change the value of a variable based on a condition using dplyr::mutate and if_else?

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

I'm trying to change a value of a variable in a data.frame where if a condition is met, then the variable takes another value, and if the condition is not met, the variable takes its original value. I'm confused why I'm getting an error and would like to know how can I modify my code to overcome this error.

For example, say I have the following dataset `x` and I want to create a new variable `var3`, such that if a condition is met, `var3` takes 1, if not `var3` takes its old value.

```
x = data.frame(var1 = c('a', 'b', 'ab'),
               var2 = rep(2,3))
x
x %>%
  dplyr::mutate(var3 = 0,
                var3 = if_else(grep('a', var1)==1, 1, var3))
```

If I run this code I get the following error

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column `var3` must be length 3 (the number of rows) or one, not 2
```

The correct answer is

```
  var1 var2 var3
1    a    2    1
2    b    2    0
3   ab    2    1
```

My real code is more complicated and I need to `var3` to take its old value when the condition evaluates `FALSE`, rather than just a singular value (say `0`).

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `grepl`:

```
x %>%
  mutate(var3 = 0, 
         var3 = if_else(grepl('a', var1), 1, var3))
```

Output:

```
  var1 var2 var3
1    a    2    1
2    b    2    0
3   ab    2    1
```

The reason is that `grep` gives you only indices of true matches, and `grepl` outputs `TRUE` or `FALSE` for each value of the vector, therefore making it possible to use it with `ifelse` (and within dataframes in general).

Answer (score 2):

Answer using str_detect:

```
library(tidyverse)

x = data.frame(var1 = c('a', 'b', 'ab'),
               var2 = rep(2,3))
x

x %>%
    dplyr::mutate(var3 = 0,
                  var3 = if_else(str_detect(var1,'a'), 1, var3))
```